# Allowing POST requests to bypass Basic Auth if on given pages

Tags: htaccess, access-control, http-authentication

Current Implementation:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^example\.com$ passreq

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /html/.htpasswd

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user

Allow from env=!passreq

# Allow GET when 'test' in query string
<FilesMatch "^(login_html|response_html)\.php$">
    <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /.*test=.*/" >
        Satisfy Any
        Allow from all
    </If>
</FilesMatch>

# Allow POST requests 
<FilesMatch "^(login_html|response_html)\.php$">
    <If "%{REQUEST_METHOD} =~ POST" >
        Satisfy Any
        Allow from all
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

I'm hoping someone can help, I trying to build a system that will allow a user to bypass basic authentication on the login page either when a query string of 'test' is passed (which seems to be working), or when the page is hit by any post request.

It's the bottom FilesMatch that is currently not working, I also need it only to apply when the Host in this case it example.com

Comment: Why are you protecting a login page with basic auth?   Basic auth has its own name/password dialog.  You shouldn't need to have an HTML based one.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's a staging site that also has single sign on from a different site. The idea is to allow everyone using it for single sign on to bypass the basic authentication.

Comment: How would this bypass basic auth for the rest of the site once the user is signed on with the SSO?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Once authenticated, the user is redirected back to their original site.

Comment: Maybe it would be appropriate to disable basic auth on the login page altogether?   I don't see a use case where users need to log in to view a log in page.

Comment: I understand why you might use Basic Auth on a staging site to keep bots away., but OAuth could do the same.  Is there some other reason you're adding Basic Auth?